# select * where distinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do something like this:

`select * from receipt where branch=:branch AND distinct transactionid`

However this is not working and brings up all results. I just need to get all the information that matches what I need and has a distinct `transaction`. So that might include firstname lastname and all the information that each listing in the database stores as I use all that information later.

Lets say I have:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| first  |  last     |  item    |  transactionid  |
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| jack   |  sparrow  |  water   |    1234         |
| jack   |  sparrow  |  food    |    1234         |
| jack   |  sparrow  |  wood    |    1234         |
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

I want all listings with the first name jack (any one of them) with a distinct transactionid...

Can this even be done?

Comment: if you have records like this, `1, 2`, `1,3` where 1 is the transactionID, what will be the output?

Comment: this `select distinct column1,column2... from table where branch = branch` can work?

Comment: can you sample records with desired result? it helps a lot :D

Comment: "I am trying to do something like `X` but it is not working". Well, that means `X` doesn't mean what you thought it means, so we cannot decode your intentions from it. Chicken and the egg... And, really, it _is_ working in the way that it is supposed to; just you picked the wrong tool for what you wanted to do, so blame your code not the tool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  transactionID, MIN(item) minItem
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY transactionID
        ) b ON a.transactionID = b.transactionID AND
                        a.item = b.minItem
// -- WHERE branch =: branch
```

**Thanks for the edit zerkms**

*so what does the subquery do?*

Well, it just *gets one item per `transactionID`*. You can also use `MAX` on it.

Comment: wait, I have never written any sql like this before so could you help me understand, where do the parts I am looking for go?

Comment: `MIN(item) minItem` what do those mean?

Comment: @Mr. Sir King Osman: if you bother opening a documentation and searched for `MIN` - you would find this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min And `minItem` is an alias

Comment: it just gets the single value for the `transactionID`. you said that *any* of the following can be item can be shown.

Comment: I did, thanks....I looked into it and thats what I needed! I thought it was something to do with my table... so please try to be nice!